# Error while importing google cloud videintelligence: ImportError: cannot import name 'init_grpc_aio' from 'grpc._cython.cygrpc'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-speech-api, video-intelligence-api

i'm trying to run:

```
from google.cloud import videointelligence
```

and i get the following error:

> from grpc._cython.cygrpc import (init_grpc_aio, shutdown_grpc_aio,
> EOF,
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'init_grpc_aio' from
> 'grpc._cython.cygrpc'
> (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc_cython\cygrpc.cp37-win_amd64.pyd)

It also happens when I try to import this

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
```

I tried to install grpc again [grpcio], but it didn't solve the problem. I haven't found any useful solution to this yet.

Anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Can you give us more details about your platform? What version of `google-cloud-videointelligence` and `google-cloud-speech` do you have installed? What's the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437141/google-cloud-videointelligence-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-api?