# Google-Cloud Videointelligence: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.api_core.operations_v1'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, video-intelligence-api

I want to use Google Cloud Videointelligence but I keep getting errors.
Now I get

```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.api_core.operations_v1'
```

I have no idea how to install said module, I couldn't find anything about this.

This is what I have installed so far:

```
google==3.0.0
google-api-core==1.22.1
google-api-python-client==1.10.0
google-auth==1.20.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.26.1
google-cloud-core==1.4.1
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.15.0
google-crc32c==0.1.0
google-gax==0.14.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==0.7.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
greenlet==0.4.15
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpc-google-longrunning-v2==0.8.1
grpcio==1.31.0
grpcio-tools==1.31.0
```

Comment: Can you ensure that `google-api-core` package has been installed `pip list| grep google-api-core`? Do you have the same issue for the different packages? How do you import `operations_v1` module in your script?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434140/error-while-importing-google-cloud-videintelligence-importerror-cannot-import?

Comment: No, it was another different error I got after the one of the first post.